# Software for removing leader lines from images

Tags: image-processing

Is any software known to remove leader lines (and labels) from images? Think of images with labels naming specific elements visible on the image with leader lines that cross the image. For instance a picture of a car with labels and lines pointing to 'door', 'wind shield', 'tyres', etc. If one wants to have the image without the lines, it is quite time consuming (and difficult) to remove the lines that cross the image and are part of the image. However, it is imaginable that this could be done with software. Does anyone possibly know of such software?

Paul

Comment: i'm not sure, but probably you are interested in [MAT](https://0xacab.org/jvoisin/mat2) or [Scrambled Exif](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.jarsilio.android.scrambledeggsif/).

Comment: I've never run across such a package. I've been re-touching images used in documentation for decades and would have done evil things to have such a package. I hope someone has an answer that doesn't involved GIMP/Photoshop and endless hours on tablet messing around with pixels.

Comment: Thank you DJCrashDummy, but I don't think MAT or Scrambled Exif will do what I meant. A quick read shows me they're for removing metadata. The issue here is image editing: basically replacing the pixels that form a leader line with the colour of the pixels of the image just adjacent to the line. It seems from Ring's response that I am not alone in my wish for such software :-)